# Xamarin, No se pudo encontrar el componente 'System.ObjectModel'

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Al ejecutar este código en xamarin, me sale esta advertencia y no me deja compilar el programa, alguien expliqueme el porque de este problema, de antemano gracias.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No me deja compilar esa advertencia

Comment: De que compila, compila, de que se puede ejecutar en el emulador y/o dispositivo, se puede. Es sólo una advertencia. En mi blog tengo unos post sobre Xamarin: http://fredyfx.com/blog/

Comment: no se ejecuta :/

Comment: compilar != ejecutar

Answer (score 1):

Lee las letritas que salen en "Salida" dicen lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí hago una pausa: ¿Vas a usar el emulador que te da el mismo Android?¿Vas a usar el emulador de Visual Studio para Android?¿Vas a usar otro emulador?

Considerando la falta de detalles en tu pregunta y viendo la salida de tu ejecución, asumiré que tienes Hyper-V funcionando y tienes instalado Visual Studio Emulators for Android. Con esto, tienes que ir a Herramientas -> Visual Studio Emulator for Android:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Selecciona el perfil que desees crear y "dale play", esto te ahorrará tiempo al momento de "debuggear" la aplicación. Cuando lo hagas, asegúrate de seleccionar el mismo perfil (al costado de la flecha verde).

Recomendaciones:

1. Siempre lee la salida, ahí hasta te dice qué hacer.
2. Siempre abre el Visual Studio con permisos de administrador.
3. En caso necesites salida a internet a en tu app, este post tiene la respuesta: [http://fredyfx.com/post/solucion-emulador-android-en-hyper-v-sin-conexión-a-internet/](http://fredyfx.com/post/solucion-emulador-android-en-hyper-v-sin-conexi%C3%B3n-a-internet/)